# Flutter Floor Database from snapshot.data in Future Builder?

Tags: database, flutter, future, floor

I can't able to store snapshot.data to database via floor in Flutter. I wrote entity, dao and database file, builded database and database.g.dart succesed to complete, but when I tried to insertUser function it turns below error;
What am I missing? Is there anything to do for record future snapshot.data which there isn't in [the guide]?[1](https://pub.dev/packages/floor)

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'insertUser' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: insertUser(Instance of 'UserF')
```

My entity:

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';

@entity
class UserF {
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
 final int id;

 final String user;
 final int overview;


 UserF({this.id,
     this.user,
     this.overview,


 @override
 int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ user.hashCode ^ overview.hashCode  ;

 @override
 String toString() {
   return 'UserF{id: $id, user: $user, overview: $overview}';
 }
}
```

DAO:

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'entity.dart';

@dao
abstract class UserDao {
 @Query('SELECT * FROM UserF')
 Future<List<UserF>> findAllUsers();

 @Query('SELECT * FROM UserF WHERE id = :id')
 Stream<UserF> findUserById(int id);

 @insert
 Future<void> insertUser(UserF userF);

 @delete
 Future<int> deleteUser(UserF userF);

}
```

Database:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqflite;
import 'user_dao.dart';
import 'entity.dart';
part 'database.g.dart'; // the generated code will be there

@Database(version: 1, entities: [UserF])
abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
 UserDao get userDao;
}
```

Related Parts on my main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async{
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 final AppDatabase = await $FloorAppDatabase
     .databaseBuilder('database.db')
     .build();

 runApp(MyApp());
}

....

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                         onPressed: (){
                           final userf = UserF(user: snapshot.data.user, overview: snapshot.data.overview);
                           favoriteDao.insertUser(userf);
                         },
                         child: Icon(Icons.add),
....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NoSuchMethod error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049102/what-is-a-nosuchmethod-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `favoriteDao` is `null`. Since you did not post any code showing us that it shouldn't be, the best guess is you forgot to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code :

```
part 'database.g.dart';
```

is creating error that means you have to generate that file.

Add these dependencies if you haven't already:

Dependencies:

```
floor: ^0.14.0
sqflite: ^1.3.0
```

Dev Dependencies:

```
floor_generator: ^0.14.0
build_runner: ^1.8.1
```

In terminal run the following command:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

And wait for some time. Flutter will generate the command.
Flutter will automatically generate the file.

REMEMBER: **THE NAME OF THE DATABASE *FILE* AND NAME OF *GENERATED FILE* MUST BE SAME EXEPT FOR ADDING .g**

For Example

if the database file name is **mydatabase.dart**
the generated file name must be **mydatabase.g.dart**

Comment: Why do you think that is the problem? The OP did not report any problem with that.